# PHP Curl Login and fetch data

Tags: php, http, curl, https

I'm trying to make an php app that that logs on Comcast on here

```
https://login.comcast.net/login
```

and download a file

```
http://xfinity.comcast.net/
```

remembering the cookie.

This is what i have so far:

```
<?php
$username="username"; 
$password="password"; 
$url="https://login.comcast.net/login"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "user=".$username."&passwd=".$password."&rm=2&deviceAuthn=false&forceAuthn=true&s=ccentral-cima&r=comcast.net&continue=http://xfinity.comcast.net/"; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents("page.txt",$ch);

echo $cookie;
?>
```

What this script does is just login, and show me

```
https://customer.comcast.com/Public/Home.aspx
```

as i was logged in, and then when i press Email for example it simply treats me like i have never logged in, requesting me username and password. All i want is to fetch the number of emails by saving http://xfinity.comcast.net/ (with a cookie) to page.txt

Can this be possible?

Comment: I'm confused a bit: first you fetch the login cookie into cookie.txt by CURL, then you try to open the page you've got within the _browser_, hoping that it will look for the cookie in cookie.txt?

Comment: Have you tried using the `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER` and `CURLOPT_REFERER` options?

Comment: you're right raina77ow, you have a point

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`. Jar is what is written into, file is being send to server.

Also, if you want to do both in one request, you have to query the server twice. Once to log in (with `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`) and second time to obtain the actual content (with `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`).

Moreover, there's no need to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `false` as the login for usually does redirect. I would change it to `true`, just to make sure.

Comment: i'll try all of those, they are clouding my mind ... if you have some spare time can you post an code on codepad? don't worry i will try those, i'm not sitting for nothing

Comment: thanks man ... but it only gives me the page http://xfinity.comcast.net/ as i'm not logged in ... i changed $url to  $url_login by the way ...

Comment: Something weird is going on. What's in the `cookie.txt` file? Is it even created? Are the privileges to write/read set?

Comment: it must be near curl_login.php? because i never seen it, and if it is not created or lost why my first code logs me in??!?!? I have big troubles with this, its very wierd.

Comment: i'm on windows wamp server btw

Comment: @Row yes, it should be in the same folder as the script itself. Would it actually create something if you pass in an absolute path instead of "cookie.txt"? Also, just try dumping it with `var_dump(file_get_contents($cookie))`, might be php can see it after all.

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(cookie.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\black\curl_login\test_login.php on line 37
bool(false)    .......... and what now?? i'm lost, how does even logs in ??!?

Comment: @Row well the post args were missing `lang` and `submit` columns, but that should make no difference. Try saving the first result to a file, see what it produced. Might also want to turn on `CURLOPT_HEADER`. And again, try an absolute path.

Comment: ok, first of all **result.txt** is just the **xfinity.comcast.net** not logged ... and header writes HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Last-Modified: Sun, 26 Feb 2012 19:05:10 GMT Expires: Sun, 26 Feb 2012 19:10:10 GMT Cache-Control: max-age=300 Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Content-Language: en-US Date: Sun, 26 Feb 2012 19:08:34 GMT Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Connection: Transfer-Encoding Set-Cookie: userZip=; expires=Wed, 25-Feb-2015 19:08:34 GMT; path=/; domain=.comcast.net ... and i see **userZip** is missing, so cookie is not there or something ...

Comment: i found it .. it doesn't remember the cookie, for example at login the header is Set-Cookie: tg_ticket=VEdUAQEAABQMAyRxQLzX1vi .... a insanely long code , so, how do i make it remember it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be handy if you put the curl lines into a function.

Now the steps should be rather easy.

**EDIT**
Make sure cookie.txt is in the same directory as your php file.
and make sure it is writable. ( chmod 777 )
to check :

```
if (is_writable('cookie.txt')) {
    echo 'The cookie is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The cookie is not writable';
    ## start by making it writable :
   if (! chmod ( 'cookie.txt', 0777 ))
        die ( 'chmod() failed on file cookie.txt' );
}
```

1. login and save login cookie data with curl. ( make sure cookie.txt exists and  is writable ).
2. Do another curl WITH cookie enabled and retrieve page.

Something like this :

```
//@param string $url : url of page/file
    //@param bool $binary : binary file.
    //@param string $post : post data in format : formvar1=VAR1&formvar2=VAR2
    //@param string $cookie : cookie file.

function curl($url ,$binary=false,$post=false,$cookie =false ){

$ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);



        if($cookie){

            $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);

        }


        if($binary)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

        if($post){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        }

     return  curl_exec ($ch);
}
```

Then login :

```
$username="username"; 
$password="password"; 
$url="https://login.comcast.net/login"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "user=".$username."&passwd=".$password."&rm=2&deviceAuthn=false&forceAuthn=true&s=ccentral-cima&r=comcast.net&continue=http://xfinity.comcast.net/"; 

// function
$ch = curl($url,false,$postdata,$cookie);
```

Logged in ? check cookie.txt for content.

Step 2 , get second page.

```
$url ='http://xfinity.comcast.net/'
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$ch =curl($url,false,false,$cookie);

echo $ch;
```

Something like that... Let me know if it works.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\xampp\htdocs\black\curl_login\test_login.php on line 3 ... i never seen this type of programming in PHP, what is this?!? and if you have time please help me, i really need this

Comment: The above 4 lines are just comments.. I commented them out now.

Comment: lol, i erase to see if the rest of the code works ... it works, shows me http://xfinity.comcast.net/ as i'm not logged in ... the cookie is lost somewhere

Comment: Then you are missing something with the login procedure.. Can I make an account there ?

Comment: Ok it is not that simple they probably have extra security measures.  Without access I cannot help you.

Comment: I made an edit , I believe it has something to do with your cookie file. Check if it is writable !

Comment: ok, and why  gist.github.com/1918103 this code logs me on a page, and don't remember when i go to  xfinity.comcast.net ? at first login i see the headers just fine  Set-Cookie: tg_ticket=VEdUAQEAABQMAyRxQLzX .... and then they mysteriously despair, why is that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8265/discussion-between-paolo-nl-fr-and-row-minds)

Comment: ok, the first time i try to log the output with the header is http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=296948&c=5034774 and then 2nd page is http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=296950&c=4418635 so the cookie must be lost somewhere

Comment: im on windows and cookie is writeble