# ftp log in and put file using PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP so please go easy!
What I want to do is the following:

- User goes to a html log in page and enters their details (these are actually their unix long-in)
- If these are correct the user is asked to enter some information and press submit
- On doing this a file is created with today's date and the content is a chosen by the user.
- This file is ftp'd to root of the users unix account
  What process should i be following to do this?

So far my PHP looks like this (but it doesn't work)

```
<?php

$ftp_server = '192.168.103.11'; //actual domain is listed here.
$ftp_username = $_POST['username'];
$ftp_password = $_POST['password'];
$location = "ftp://$ftp_username:$ftp_password@$ftp_server";
$dest = '/home/detica/mjm/'
$source = '/var/www/html/test.txt'
$mode = 'FTP_ASCII'

$ftp_connect_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$ftp_login = ftp_login($ftp_connect_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);
if (! $ftp_connect_id || ! $ftp_login)
{
echo "Unable to connect to $ftp_server";
exit;
} else {
header("Location: $location");
echo "Connected to host $ftp_server";

$upload = ftp_put($ftp_connect_id, $dest, $source, $mode);

if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

ftp_close(ftp_connect_id);
}
ftp_close($ftp_connect_id);
?>
```

Comment: You've jumped right into the deep end of the pool now haven't you?

Comment: This is a lot of separate tasks.... one pointer to get you started [PHP Curl Login and fetch data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9455376)

Comment: Why do you need to FTP? PHP is a server-side language.  If PHP is on the server the file needs to be "FTP'd" to, why FTP it? Why not just move the uploaded file to the user's unix account?

Answer (score 1):

Heres something I quickly put together, ill leave you to finish it off ;p hope it helps.

```
<?php 
/**
 * A simple FTP crud class
 */
Class ftp_it{

    public $status;

    function __construct($host,$user,$pass){
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->status = 'Ready';
    }

    /*Singleton FTP Connect*/
    private function connect(){
        if (!isset($this->ftp)){
            $this->ftp = ftp_connect($this->host, 21, 3) or die ("Cannot connect to host");
            ftp_login($this->ftp, $this->user, $this->pass) or die("Cannot login");
            ftp_pasv($this->ftp, true);
            $this->status = 'Connected';
        }
    }

    public function get($local_file,$ftp_path){
        $this->connect();
        if(ftp_get($this->ftp, $local_file, $ftp_path,  FTP_BINARY)) {
            $this->status = 'Download complete';
        }else{
            $this->status = 'Cannot download';
        }
    }

    public function put($local_file,$ftp_path){
        $this->connect();
        if(ftp_put($this->ftp, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
            $this->status = 'Upload complete';
        }else{
            $this->status = 'Cannot upload';
        }
    }

    public function delete($ftp_path){
        $this->connect();
        if (ftp_delete($this->ftp, $ftp_path)) {
            $this->status = "$ftp_path deleted successful";
        }else{
            $this->status = "Could not delete $ftp_path";
        }
    }

    public function make_dir($dir){
        $this->connect();
        if (ftp_mkdir($this->ftp, $dir)) {
            $this->status = "Successfully created $dir";
        } else {
            $this->status = "Could not create $dir";
        }
    }

    public function delete_dir($dir){
        $this->connect();
        if (ftp_rmdir($this->ftp, $dir)) {
            $this->status = "Successfully deleted $dir\n";
        } else {
            $this->status = "Could not delete $dir\n";
        }
    }

    public function show_files($dir='/'){
        $this->connect();
        return ftp_nlist($this->ftp, $dir);
    }

    private function close(){
        ftp_close($this->ftp);
    }

    function __destruct(){
        if(isset($this->ftp)){
            $this->close();
        }
    }
}//END Class


//Has user posted form?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //Assign values from form ill leave you to workout validation
    $content  = $_POST['content'];
    $filename = $_POST['fn'];
    //Host creds
    $host = $_POST['host'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    //Start FTP crud
    $ftp = new ftp_it($host,$user,$pass);
    //Some other options  ;)
    //$ftp->get('./DOWN/test.txt','/test.txt');
    //$ftp->delete('/test.txt');
    //$ftp->make_dir('/test');
    //$ftp->delete_dir('/test');
    //$ftp->show_files('/');

    //Create A temp file for the POSTEd Contents
    $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FTP");
    $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
    //Write it to file
    fwrite($handle, $content);
    fclose($handle);

    //Upload the file
    $ftp->put($tmpfname,'/'.$filename);

    //Status
    echo $ftp->status;
}else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Save this to my FTP</title>
<style>
*{padding:0px; margin:0px;}
#outer{padding:5px;}
</style>
</head>

<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">

<div id="outer">
<form method="POST" action="">
<h1>Save this to my FTP</h1>
  <p>The Content:</p>
  <p><textarea rows="8" name="content" cols="62"></textarea></p>
  <p>Filename: <input type="text" name="fn" size="22"></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
  Host: <input type="text" name="host" size="15">
  Username: <input type="text" name="user" size="14">
  Password: <input type="text" name="pass" size="14">
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>

</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>

</html> 
<?php }?>
```